# How to design textbox visibility expression in SSRS?

Tags: t-sql, expression, visibility, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an RDL with a table/textbox visibility set to:

```
=iif(Fields!question_caption.Value = "OBJECTIVE 1",false,true)
```

I am trying to make this textbox display the value named "narrative" only if the question_caption record = "OBJECTIVE 1".   How can I do this?  Currently this textbox displays nothing with the above logic.  I have the narrative field stored in a Placeholder if that makes any difference.

Here is some sample data for you:

```
create table #dummy_data
(
question_caption varchar(max),
narrative varchar(max)
)
insert #dummy_data values('1st week dates','week 1'),('2nd week dates','week 2'),('3rd week dates','week 3'),('OBJECTIVE 1','obj 1'),
('5th week dates','week 5')
select * from #dummy_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your visibility expression. However, in your question, you're discussing two separate things as one (i.e., visibility & displaying a value in a placeholder).

The hidden property will show an **object** (tablix, textbox, image, chart, container, etc) if the expression returns false and will hide an object when the expression returns true. When I say hide, I mean that it will remove the object from the grid and, if all is setup properly, the surrounding objects will be shifted to fill the now empty space of the hidden object.

To display (or not) a **value** is an entirely different thing. To show or hide a value, you would put the following expression in the value property of the placeholder:

```
=IIF(Fields!question_caption.Value = "OBJECTIVE 1",Fields!narrative.Value,"")
```

Notice that I've set it up such that if the desired value of the *question_caption* field is present, it will display the value of the *narrative* field. Otherwise, it will return an empty string. This will maintain the layout of the report but simply display the desired value or an empty string, based on some criteria.

As for the issues you're current experiencing, I'm not sure why that would be happening. I would first check that you don't have a typo in the *Objective 1* hardcoded value in your expression.

If this doesn't help, please comment and let me know some more information about your problem and I'll do my best to help.